# If then as matrix calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

Having simple script code a like to bring a if-then-condition into linear algebra form. How is it made?

Example 1: Having $T=25$ (where T is temperature current in room). If $T>30$ the equ. schould rise a $1$.

Thats maybe simple, but when a second condition comes in, we go harder:

Example 2: Having $T=25$ an $W=1$ (Window open/closed$=0$) we should get "close Window".

How is that made?

Answer (score 2):

Linear algebra and matrix calculations deal with *linear* problems. That means that if $u$ and $v$ are answers to the problem, and $c$ is a constant real number, then $u+v$ and $cu$ are also answers to the problem. (I simplify a bit, but that is the general idea.)

The examples you give are not linear. Doubling the beginning temperature does not double the ending temperature, for example.

We conclude that your examples cannot be done directly by matrices or linear algebra.

That said, *parts* of your problems can be done by matrices, but that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I got your point. But: Is it possible to reduce the u and v to a linear behaviour?

Comment: I'm looking for this approach as done for sudoku: One other method which can be implemented in Matlab is to use the matrix structure of the Sudoku table and write the constraints of non repetition on lines, columns and 3 \times 3 blocks as linear constraints [link]https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/solve-a-sudoku-puzzle-using-matlab/[/link]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to do, but not with just one matrix multiplication. If you allow many matrix multiplications you can build a discrete matrix.

For instance the matrix:

$${\bf M} = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$

will rotate the last row one step to the right for each matrix multiplication. Though you may consider this to be more of an engineering trick than linear algebra.

With a large enough matrix, we can encode the output value as a particular element of the last row and let the exponent encode the input variable.

For instance ${\bf M}^4 = \left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0
\end{array}\right]$

So in our minimal example the output value will become 1 at the first time for 4 degrees if we choose the output value to be index (7,6).